# Nginx will not listen on ipv4 port 443

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, https

Nginx will not listen on ipv4 port 443.  It listens on ipv4/6 port 80 and ipv6 port 443 but not ipv4 port 443.

Debian Stretch 9.8 - currently updated

Installed nginx-full package with apt

```
root@loadbalance01:/etc/nginx# nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/1.10.3
```

After doing:

```
systemctl stop nginx
systemctl start nginx

root@loadbalance01:/etc/nginx# !166
netstat -anop | grep LISTEN | grep nginx
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      13533/nginx: master  off (0.00/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      13533/nginx: master  off (0.00/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      13533/nginx: master  off (0.00/0/0)
```

Conspicuously absent is port 443 on tcp.

Just to be sure nothing else is listening on tcp 443

```
root@loadbalance01:/etc/nginx# netstat -anop | grep LISTEN | grep ':443'
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      13533/nginx: master  off (0.00/0/0)
```

Nope only tcp6.

The only errors in /var/log/nginx/error.log are old errors that have been corrected.

```
nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

My config:

I am just trying to create a simple load balancer with 1 node till I can show this works.

nginx.conf
Note this is only modified by removing the sites-enabled line, I am using a conf.d config.

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

The only other file modified is:

```
root@loadbalance01:/etc/nginx# cat conf.d/loadbalance.conf

upstream example {
    server 192.168.1.250;
}

server {
    server_name example.com

    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    ssl on;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://example;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name _;

    return 301 https://example.com;
}
```

NOTE: renamed to example.com

Comment: With linux by default, when a process listens on the ipv6 port, ipv4 connections will also come into that socket. So a separate listener on ipv4 is not needed and probably not even possible because of this.

Comment: I tried a telnet 192.168.1.249 443 from another server on the same lan and it says connection refused.

Comment: You’ve missed semicolon after `server_name` directive, so you don’t have `listen 443 ssl` directive, but instead you have weird server names `listen`, `443` and `ssl`.

Comment: And, btw, you don’t need `ssl on`

Answer (score 1):

Thanx to Alexy Ten,

The configuration was missing a semi colon after the server name directive.   It passed syntax check, but was still wrong.

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

I have not had huge experience with nginx but i have used the following configuration file successfully for reverse proxying / load balancing.
Hopefully something in this will help you

```
# HTTP Server redirect to HTTPS
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name <WEB_NAME>.example.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

# HTTPS Server
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name <WEB_NAME>.example.com;

    # It is best to place the root of the server block at the server level, and not the location level
    # any location block path will be relative to this root. 
    root /site/<WEB_NAME>;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/<WEB_NAME>.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/<WEB_NAME>.error.log;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/<WEB_NAME>/example.com.cer;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/<WEB_NAME>/example.com.nopass.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # don't use SSLv3 ref: POODLE
    ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;


    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forward-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forward-Proto http;
        proxy_set_header X-Nginx-Proxy true;

        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}


# Uncomment other server entries if Loadbalance Configuration is required
upstream backend {
    server 127.0.0.1:80;
#    server <BACKEND_SERVER2>:<PORT>;
#    server <BACKEND_SERVER3>:<PORT>;
}
```

**NOTE: also renamed to example.com ;)

Answer (score 0):

In my case 443 was blocked on an instance networking level on Lightsail. Had to go to it's settings and allow it.